# Kernel of Hurewicz map using the spectral sequence of the universal cover

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

In Davis & Kirk's Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology, Exercise 159 reads:

> Use the spectral sequence of the universal cover to show that for a path-connected space $X$ the sequence $$\pi_2(X)\stackrel{\rho}{\to} H_2(X)\to H_2(\pi_1(X))\to 0$$ is exact.

Here $\rho$ is the Hurewicz map and the (homology) s.s. of the universal cover has 
$E^2_{p,q}=H_p(\pi_1(X);H_q(\tilde{X}))\Rightarrow H_{p+q}(X)$.

So far I have a short exact sequence 
$$0\to \pi_2^*(X)/d_3(H_3(\pi_1(X)))\to H_2(X)\to H_2(\pi_1(X))\to 0$$ 
By $\pi^*_2(X)$ I mean the quotient of $\pi_2(X)$ by the action of the fundamental group. This is $E^2_{0,2}$ in our sequence by some covering space theory. $H_2(\pi_1(X))$ survives all the way to $E^\infty$ because the whole row $E^2_{p,1}$ is zero since $\tilde{X}$ is connected.

So, my question is this: is the kernel of $\rho:\pi_2^*(X)\to H_2(X)$ simply $d_3(H_3(\pi_1(X)))$, and how can I see this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

COMPLETE OVERKILL!  Just take universal covering fibration $\pi_1(X) \hookrightarrow \tilde{X} \to X$, deloop it once to get the fibration $\tilde{X} \to X \to B \pi_1(X)$.  I claim that the serre exact sequence of this fibration is the required exact sequence.

It is $H_2(\tilde{X}) \to H_2(X) \to H_2(B \pi_1(X)) \xrightarrow{transgression} H_1(\tilde{X})$.  The transgression is well defined here because it is just $d_2$ acting on $E^2_{2,0}=H_2(B \pi_1(X))$.(In general the transgression is $d_n$ acting on a subgroup of $H_n(base of fibration)$, and to show the transgression is well defined one has to show that $d_{i}=0$ for all $2\leq i<n$).

The hurewizc naturality square applied to the map $\tilde{X} \to X$ implies that $H_2(\tilde{X}) \to H_2(X)$ is in fact the hurewicz map $\pi_2(X) \to H_2(X)$.

Thus we have an exact sequence $\pi_2(X) \xrightarrow{hurewicz} H_2(X) \to H_2(K(\pi_1(X),1)) \to 0=H_1(\tilde{X})$.